# Xampp Ports openning without administrator rights

Tags: xampp, ports

I am developing a web application ofline using Xampp. I am working offline for this an a machine with administrator rights. I tried running it on my work machine but Apache and SQL will not start because of the ports. What rights do I need to set from the admin user in order to give all time acces for this programs? (I do need to go to the IT desk and ask them to do it, so I need a working solution)

Comment: Appache by default uses ports 80 and 443 common programs that use these ports are Skype, IIS, ... You can change the port xampp uses see http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-the-apache-port-in-xampp In most cases you don't need adminstrator rights as since you're running xampp locally (This statement changes when you want someone else to connect to your pc and webserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an easy fix after all. I just asked the IT staff to log in as administrator and give permisions to the xampp folder for everything. This does not endager the company policy.